# Restrict access of public classes within library only on Android

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I'm developing a library for Android that I want to distribute but I want to restrict access to some public classes only within the library. The current structure of my library is something like:

```
lib
|--- pkg1
|     |---- ClassA
|
|--- pkg2
      |---- ClassB
```

I want to access ClassA from ClassB but I don't want users to access ClassA. I've separated packages based on functionality like network calls, business logic etc. but this hierarchy doesn't allow me to access classes from other sub-packages in the library if `package-private` modifier is used and with `public` modifier, modules like `app` can access my classes that I want to restrict.

Comment: If `ClassA` needs something from `ClassB` then `ClassB` shouldn't be in a different package. The only way how to expose class from a package is by making it `public`.

Comment: @TheLibrarian Would it be ok, according to convention, to put `ClassB` with `ClassA` if `ClassA` is used only for network calls and `ClassB` uses those network calls to create objects that are then used by developers that use the library?

Comment: That's a very loaded question and there is basically no context to say so but I think what you are basically missing is a public interface(don't mean code-wise) to those packages. If you want those classes to be self-sufficient, they need to have public ways how to get data in and how to get data out without them knowing where they came from or what someone is gonna do with them.

Comment: @TheLibrarian Well what I want to achieve is that, the classes can be in the same package but for the sake of organization of different files, I want to have them in separate directories without using packages. I'm not sure if something like that can be achieved.